# Add a web part (listview) using an existing folder location

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server

Using SharePoint server 2007 - I would like to create a web part to display the contents of a folder that already exists in the domain.

How would i go about completing this task?

Comment: Folder? Meaning network file share?

Comment: yes - it is a location on a file server that is loaded with existing documents.

Comment: Page Viewer Web Part is not working? It supports file shares as well.

Comment: the page viewer web part only allows for a URL.   I need the web part to display the contents of a folder (network share)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Page Viewer Web Part to display folders. You need to type in the address in format like `file://\\somenetworkserver\networkfolder`.

Or you can use 3rd party web part, like [this](http://networkshare.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I've used page viewer web parts exactly as Jussi describes, you just have to make sure the people who have access to the file share have access to Sharepoint and vice versa.

Comment: Sad day on the farm - yes, the answer does work...  bad news is, it only works for IE...    suggestions would be appreciated on how to get around this limit, without going to a third party tool.

Comment: True, IE only. It's some ActiveX component so getting that to reliably work on other browsers is pretty much impossible. You can try tricks like described here, but I haven't tried those in years so unsure if recent Chrome for example has blocked these completely: http://support.myvisionexpress.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/444/154/how-to-activate-activex-for-google-chrome--firefox-for-single-sign-on-feature-for-rd-web-access